# Getting date object from jquery ui datepicker maxDate option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, maxdate

By using the following

```
var maxDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate" );
```

The output can be anything from '+1M','+20Y', '12/12/2013' or more..

Are the '+1M' & '+20Y' examples something that can be used with native javascript to add to the current date so I'd be able to get an actual date object?

I would like to use this to validate the following function that is used by a set of presets (Current Week, Month, Day etc)

```
function SetDate(dateFrom, dateTo) {
        $('.dateFrom').attr('value', dateFrom);
        $('.dateTo').attr('value', dateTo);
    }
```

[Reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more searching I found [this answer to "jQuery datepicker getMinDate '+1d'"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886384/151625)

I decided to use the second example the user posted:

```
var minDateAttr = $(elem).datepicker("option", "minDate");
var inst = $(elem).data("datepicker");
var minDateObj = $.datepicker._determineDate(inst, minDateAttr, new Date());
```