# how to convert datepicker minimum date (+10y) to date time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker, whose min date is set to 10y like below.

```
$('#starttime').datepicker({
    ampm: true,
    showHour: true,
    showMinute: true,
    showSecond: false,
    showMillisec: false,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
    hourGrid: 4,
    stepHour: 1,
    minDate: '+10y',
    maxDate: maxDate,
    stepMinute: 10
 });
```

now, how can i get mindate of datepicker in date format?? on `$('#starttime').datepicker('option','minDate');` i am getting value `+10y`. but i need the result as date time.

Comment: So are you using `datetimepicker` or `datepicker`, you seem to be mixing them ?

Comment: And you realize your datepicker would start in 2026, and no date before that would be selectable ?

Comment: you can refer -[This Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139378/setting-min-date-in-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the minDate by using the below approach, here's the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hqwpbusn/), here's the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618135/getting-date-object-from-jquery-ui-datepicker-maxdate-option)

```
<input type="text" id="starttime"/>

$(document).ready(function () {
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 30);

  $('#starttime').datepicker({
    ampm: true,
    showHour: true,
    showMinute: true,
    showSecond: false,
    showMillisec: false,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
    hourGrid: 4,
    stepHour: 1,
    minDate: '+10y',
    maxDate: maxDate,
    stepMinute: 10
 });

 var minDateAttr = $('#starttime').datepicker("option", "minDate");
 var inst = $('#starttime').data("datepicker");
 var minDateObj = $.datepicker._determineDate(inst, minDateAttr, new Date());
 console.log(minDateObj);
});
```

Comment: working.. thank you